# How to write files to assets folder or raw folder in android?

Tags: android

I am working on some application where I have to update some files present in assets / raw folder runtime from some http location.

Can anyone help me to by sharing how to write files in assets or raw folder?

Comment: assets/raw folders don't exist on the phone. They're compiled into the package

Answer (score 150, accepted):

It cannot be done. It is impossible.

Comment: Actually, I've done it with a view glitch (a webview showed my my java source code and then the html file it loaded from assets contained my java source code without spaces or anything). I am currently looking around for how to recreate it.

Answer (score 16):

Why not update the files on the local file system instead?
You can read/write files into your applications sandboxed area.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Other alternatives you may want to look into are Shared Perferences and using Cache Files (all described at the link above)

Answer (score 14):

You cannot write data's to **asset/Raw** folder, since it is packed(**.apk**) and not expandable in size.

If your application need to download dependency files from server, you can go for APK Expansion Files provided by android (http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for same issue may help you
Read and write file in private context of application

```
                 String NOTE = "note.txt";  
                 private void writeToFile() {
        try {
         OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(
                NOTES, 0));

         out.write("testing");
         out.close();
         }

        catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), 2000).show();
        }
             }


           private void ReadFromFile()
      {
        try {
        InputStream in = openFileInput(NOTES);
        if (in != null) {
            InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tmp);
            String str;
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(str + "\n");
            }
            in.close();
            String temp = "Not Working";
            temp = buf.toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, temp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
        // that's OK, we probably haven't created it yet
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), 2000).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can't write JSON file while in assets. as already described assets are read-only. But you can copy assets (json file/anything else in assets ) to local storage of mobile and then edit(write/read) from local storage. More storage options like shared Preference(for small data) and sqlite database(for large data) are available.