# android webview include javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

Might be a silly question but I don't know how to include the src URL for my javascript into the Webview?

I build a huge html tag in code, passing in variables, and then print them using flot diagrams. The javascript files reside in my asset folder, so in static html page I simply refer to them as file:///android_asset/jquery.flot.js.

But how do I do that when it's all built up by code? This doesn't seem to work

```
"<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"file:///android_asset/jquery.flot.js\"></script>" +
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure your references are right, second... research if you can include a local Javascript, cause I'm not sure of that.

But why don't you try generating the Javascript code (read from the file) whitin the `<script>` tag? Maybe it could be a solution.

***Edited:***

Have you had a look to this? It's on WebView's `public void loadDataWithBaseURL (String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl)` [method description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Note for post 1.0. Due to the change
>   in the WebKit, the access to asset
>   files through "file:///android_asset/"
>   for the sub resources is more
>   restricted. If you provide null or
>   empty string as baseUrl, you won't be
>   able to access asset files. If the
>   baseUrl is anything other than
>   http(s)/ftp(s)/about/javascript as
>   scheme, you can access asset files for
>   sub resources.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps it's impossible to include local javascript from code, it works well when using the mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about.html") with included js. I noted that the loadData() function which I use in this case can't access resources on the network, so perhaps loadin all the three js files into the <script> tag is the only solution available

Comment: @elwis, you may want to check my edited answer. Have you already read that?

Comment: @mdelolmo : Yes i'm creating within the <script> tag and I'm using loadDataWithBaseURL to load web page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760626/how-to-write-files-to-assets-folder-or-raw-folder-in-android
It seems it's not possible to write files in asset folder..