# What's the way to access the assets-folder in an Android project?

Tags: java, android, file, edit

I access to an XML file placed in a project folder (for instance 'assets') for open and read data from file.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputStream iS = this.getAssets().open("myFile.xml");  
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(iS);
```

but If I want to edit the file, I can't find the path to save it.

```
TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
                //create string from xml tree
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                trans.transform(source, result);
                String xmlString = sw.toString();
                OutputStream f0;
            byte buf[] = xmlString.getBytes();
            **f0 = new FileOutputStream("/assets/wines.xml");**
            //f0 = new FileOutputStream("file:///assets/wines.xml");
            for(int i=0;i<buf .length;i++) {
               f0.write(buf[i]);
            }
            f0.close();
            buf = null;
```

I obtain always a `FileNotFoundException` at line:

```
f0 = new FileOutputStream("/assets/wines.xml");
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to `edit or write` file to `assets or raw folder`. I guess it is not possible. [It cannot be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760626/how-to-write-files-to-assets-folder-or-raw-folder-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Bettery try saving it to sd card or internal storage

Use `File sdDir = [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()][1];` to get the sdcard path.

And don't forget to give permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```