# How to save back into a file in assets folder

Tags: android, file, assets

I understand I can open a file in assets folder like this.

```
InputStream is = ((Activity) mView).getAssets().open("some.txt");
```

But what should I do to save back to the same file? I mean how do I get OutputStream of the same file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per my knowledge **you can't** because `/asset` directory is not writeable, So you can't make any changes on file which are in /asset directory, **Its because Android .apk file is only readable.**

For more info look at this discussion [Writing to file Assets folder](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/17085e83146e47d0#) And this SO question [How to write files to assets folder or raw folder in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760626/how-to-write-files-to-assets-folder-or-raw-folder-in-android)

Comment: I was afraid that. Thanks for quick response.