# How can i store a image in asset/subfolder in android? is there any maximum limit of asset folder size?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write files to assets folder or raw folder in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760626/how-to-write-files-to-assets-folder-or-raw-folder-in-android)

How can i store a image in asset/subfolder in android? is there any  maximum limit of asset folder size?
actully i am getting a bunch of image from web and trying to download all image in a subfolder in asset ? is it possible and how?
actully my code is as follows, it save the image in sdcard :-

```
String filepath=null;
      try {
       //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
       //this is the file to be downloaded
       URL url = new URL(Url);
       //create the new connection
       HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

       //set up some things on the connection
       urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
       urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); 
        //and connect!
       urlConnection.connect();
       //set the path where we want to save the file
       //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
       //sd card.
     File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
       //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
       //which we want to save the file as.

       String filename= "downloadedFile.png";   // you can download to any type of file ex:.jpeg (image) ,.txt(text file),.mp3 (audio file)
       Log.i("Local filename:",""+filename);
       file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename);
       if(file.createNewFile())
       {
        file.createNewFile();
       }

       //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
       FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

       //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
       InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

       //this is the total size of the file
       int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
       //variable to store total downloaded bytes
       int downloadedSize = 0;

       //create a buffer...
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

       //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
       while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
        //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
        fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
        downloadedSize += bufferLength;
        //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
        Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;

       }
       //close the output stream when done
       fileOutput.close();
       if(downloadedSize==totalSize)   filepath=file.getPath();

      //catch some possible errors...
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       filepath=null;
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      Log.i("filepath:"," "+filepath) ;
```

Kindly provide me some solution for that.

Comment: possible duplicate discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760626/how-to-write-files-to-assets-folder-or-raw-folder-in-android     and     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788519/is-it-possible-to-save-image-in-assets-folder-from-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not store images in asset folder problematically

it's **READ-ONLY**

And generally MAX size for asset folder is **1 MB for each file**

You can save image in sdcard.

Comment: MAX size is no more **1 MB** you can have files with big size in you assets folder.

Comment: What do you mean by hiding? Nothing you store on the device will ever be entirely secure, but Internal Storage might be sufficient: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal ?

Comment: Thanks to all for valuable comments ,and sugesstion.
now i put all the images in a subfolder in sdcard .