# Fatal Signal 11 Error: Read a file from a native method in ndk eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, file, android-ndk

I need to read a file in the native(c program) method built for ndk. I gave user permission to write external storage in manifest file. I have tried simple `fopen` with location to the file in my laptop. I also pushed it to `/data/data/package_path/file` and used this path. Nothing seem to work. Kindly provide a code snippet on how to read a file.

Thanks

Comment: External storage is not your laptop's disk, but `/sdcard` or maybe `/sdcard1`

Comment: how to copy it to /sdcard for reading the file? Also, why am I unable to read the file even after pushing it to /data/data/package_path/file? Sorry if its too naive.

Comment: To begin with, try `adb push c:\qqq\file.txt /sdcard` and try to **fopen("/sdcard/file.txt", "r")**

Comment: If you're getting a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) while reading a file, you might be reading past the end of the buffer. Post the section of code that is crashing. (If you're not sure where it's crashing, attach a debugger, or just add lots of logging until you find the spot where it dies.)

Comment: @fadden it is crashing at the `fopen` command. The program works fine without this command

Comment: @AlexCohn: I pushed it to the sd card and am able to see the file in the emulator. But when I run the `fopen` command nothing happens. Nothing prints on the screen, no error pop up. I am confused

Comment: Now I am confused. Did you print the result of fopen to log?

Comment: @AlexCohn: yes. If you find time, could you post an answer with a code snippet on how I can read from a file from native code. Also, I have seen posts on how to get the correct location of sdcard which in my case seems to be the problem.  Kindly mention in the snippet also on how to get the path for sdcard. I am using eclipse btw. Thanks a lot!