# read and write to a file in apk

Tags: java, android, xml, apk

There is a file strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string name="param">0</string>
```

need to read a variable named "param" and change it to another int variable
or read and write to a file located in this APK, for example /assets/config.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to modify the APK.

You should consider using other "persistent storage" options for your `Android` application ... you don't really want to be modifying the contents of your APK on the device. `Shared Preferences`, `External Storage` or `SQLite Databases` are among the options you have. You may want to read more documentation about these options [on the Android developer area here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: I need to edit the APK that when transferring it to another device, the settings have already been put into this apk.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your "clarification". Are you talking about what you need to do to publish a new version of an "APK" file? Otherwise, why aren't you using a "publish" / "distribute" model for your application?

Comment: I will try to explain easier: if I somehow changed the application on my device and transferred it to you, then you it will be with the same changes.

Comment: You do not want to use that vector as a way maintain and distribute your application. (Well, you may want to, but it is fraught with security issues.)

Comment: I need to do it as a defense against the free distribution of my application, because android lvl does not fit.

Comment: You are NOT planning on distributing your application using Google Play !??

Comment: No, I am plainning to distributing my paid application on Google Play, but it not protect against transfer the app to another device (for example bluetooth).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write/modify file in assets folder runtime. 
Please check [How to write files to assets folder or raw folder in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760626/how-to-write-files-to-assets-folder-or-raw-folder-in-android)