# Writing to android assets directory at runtime?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-assets

I get html snippets updates from a network request and need to insert them into a local html file that can then be fetched with `webView.loadUrl` at runtime.

I can easily load the file from `/android_assets/myFile.html` using `webView.loadUrl`, but I cannot write to the file because the `/android_assets` directory is not accessible at runtime: [Writing to /android_assets at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3760684/5620779)

So my question is, is there another location I can place the `myFile.html` so I can write to it at runtime and load it into the `webView` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asset directory is read only, you can not change it dynamically.
You can read & white files in the flowing directories:

```
Context.getFilesDir()
```

No permission required
Typical position: /data/data/app.package.name/files/

```
Context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
```

Requires WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE when api level <= 18
Typical position: /sdcard/Android/data/app.package.name/files/

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Requires WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
Typical position: /sdcard/

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you should load content from html, modify it, and save it to storage.

```
Usage: String yourData = LoadData("myFile.html");

public String LoadData(String inFile) {
        String tContents = "";

    try {
        InputStream stream = getAssets().open(inFile);

        int size = stream.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        stream.read(buffer);
        stream.close();
        tContents = new String(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exceptions here
    }

    return tContents;    
 }
```

To load your data in WebView. Call loadData() method of WebView

```
webView.loadData(yourData, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This does not precisely answer the question because `getAssets()` method still reaches into `/android_assets` directory. I was looking for other location for HTML file that changes. However, your answer was still very helpful!